# In orientdb exporting the class from json to excel

Tags: orientdb, nosql

Can anyone please tell me how to export data in the class (table) to excel format?I want to export all data from the class to excel?

Comment: I don't think is possible, according to the documentation the exported file is in the exported JSON format. For more information: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Export-and-Import.html

Comment: where is that JSON format file in orientdb?we can convert it from json to excel right?

Comment: Can you please tell me "where will i get JSON format" so that i can convert it to excel from online converter.

Comment: Please show the work you have done, with code if possible. As is, there is little information.

Comment: To have the JSON you have to export the database, by command line or with the tab in Studio

Comment: i dont want to export entire data base..i want only some tables from the datbase.